# How to get back the value using reflection in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, itext

I have a requirement in which user select the size of pdf that is generated dynamically.

To populate all sizes supported by iTextSharp I am enumerating all sizes in a dropdownlist as

```
      System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fi = typeof(iTextSharp.text.PageSize).GetFields();
      DropDownList1.DataSource = fi;
      DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Every thing is ok till here.
Now when user select say letter size, how can i use this information for initializing the document which is initialized like

```
var document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
```

Currently i am trying to get it like this but its giving compile type error.

```
PageSize getpsize()
 {
      System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fi = typeof(iTextSharp.text.PageSize).GetFields();
      int si = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;
      PageSize p = fi[si];
      return p;
 }
```

Please help as this is my first serious experience with reflection.

Comment: Actually you do not have to use reflection at all.  The PageSize constants merely are often used example sites, not a limitation. Simply offer any size you want.

Comment: "example sites" should have been "example sizes"; sometimes my smart phone is just not smart enough to understand me... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fi = typeof(iTextSharp.text.PageSize).GetFields();
```

`FieldInfo[]` is array of fields metadata, not the objects themselves.

So after you get the necessary metadata, you need to get actual field value like this:

```
FieldInfo field = fi[si];
PageSize size = (PageSize)field.GetValue(null);
```

GetValue(object) returns actual value of the field. As these fields are static, you pass null, as there is no specific object to query.